# C# Unity GetKeyuP() not being detected properly

Tags: c#, runtime-error, game-development

I'm trying to program a jump like the game "JumpKing" in C#, when GetkeyUp is executed to jump diagonally once it jumps correctly but then it jumps 1 time up and again ok and so on loop 1 and 1. I think the error is in the Rigidbody2d that controls the horizontal axis but I couldn't fix it. I tried with Update and FixedUpdate but it doesn't solve it.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MovimientoDeJugador : MonoBehaviour
{

    // Var //
                 //jumpForceX//
    public float fuerzaDeSaltoX = 0.0f;

                 //jumpForceY//
    public float fuerzaDeSaltoY = 0.0f;

                //velocity//
    public float velocidad = 0.0f;

              //input Force//
    public float fuerzaDeEntrada;


    private Rigidbody2D rb2d;

    void Start()
    {
        rb2d = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

        fuerzaDeSaltoX = 2f;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        fuerzaDeEntrada = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

        //CheckGrounded//onGround(true)//
        if (RevisarSuelo.estaEnElSuelo)
        {
            rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(fuerzaDeEntrada * velocidad, rb2d.velocity.y);


            if (Input.GetKey("space") && fuerzaDeSaltoY <= 10)
            {
                fuerzaDeSaltoY += 0.01f;
            }

            if (Input.GetKeyUp("space"))
            {
                rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(fuerzaDeSaltoX, fuerzaDeSaltoY);
                fuerzaDeSaltoY = 0f;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Method differences:
1.GetKey returns true when the key specified by the name is held down by the user
2.GetKeyDown Returns true for the frame when the user presses the button with the specified name.
3. GetKeyUp returns true in the frame when the user releases the button with the given name.Try using the "GetKeyDown" method.

Comment: @Housheng-MSFT I tried it but when using GetKeyDown the character jumps in 2 steps, when holding down the Bar it accumulates jump force and then when pressing again it jumps, with GetKeyUp once it jumps correctly and once only vertically, so I discovered the Jump Script has conflicts with the Move Script, when I remove the Move Script the Jump Script works correctly but obviously I can't move horizontally

Comment: In general please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now. Your code is in `c#`. Your question is also not about `visual-studio`

Answer (score 0):

Your situation is not very clear to me.
From what I read in the code and from your question, you can go left and right.
You can hold to increase the jump force that applies when you release the space key.
Your problem is that if you press the space key several times, the player will go higher and higher.
If so it should work. The only thing that can cause problems is the "” variable “RevisarSuelo.estaEnElSuelo". It should indicate whether it touches the floor or not, but how do you do it? Where is that variable changed in the code?
You could just do like this:

```
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.collider.name == _terrainName)
            RevisarSuelo.estaEnElSuelo = true;
    }

    private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.collider.name == _terrainName)
            RevisarSuelo.estaEnElSuelo = false;
    }
```